# How to slow down the producer in Akka-Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I"m trying to solve a problem with akka-streams. I want that my initial producer continuously fetch a queue/mongodb collection and do it within a configured interval.  What is a common practice to realize it?

Comment: Edit: It seems that Source.tick is a legit method to solve this problem. It allows emitting input periodically with using a specified interval. It can be found in : akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.tick(..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean at a fixed time interval?

Start with `Source.tick(...).map(loadFromMongo)`?

Put in a [conflate that drops ticks](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#Dropping_elements) to prevent querying the db more often than downstream can handle, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, there is a concept called throttle. It can be used as follow:

```
Source(...).throttle(50, 1.second, 1, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
```

It allows you to specify a fetching interval e.g above 50 items per second. An example can be found in the documentation here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-quickstart.html#Time-Based_Processing